# Excluding /Library (sic, not ~/Library) from Time Machine

Tags: macos, time-machine

Is there anything - at all - of value I will lose as a user, by excluding /Library?

Let's assume that rebuilding from the backup to a new machine is *not* important.

So, what is important is absolutely not losing any of my Notes notes, email,   perhaps Calendar materiel, etc., from Apple apps.

Specifically what will be lost if I exclude /Library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple and third-party applications may have a variety of subsidiary files stored in /Library.
Much of it will be in `/Library/Application Support`.

Third-party fonts may be in the `Fonts` subfolder.

But there may also be Dictionaries, Color Profiles, LaunchAgents, Privileged Helper Tools, system-wide Preferences (including network settings), printer drivers, QuickLook and Spotlight plug-ins, AppleScript Scripting Additions, Frameworks, and so much more, depending on what you've installed. Anything for which there's a named folder!

My advice is that you probably won't save much space on a backup disk by excluding /Library, and if something goes wrong, it's easier to restore one file or one folder than have to re-install a whole load of applications and the OS just to be sure.

Comment: `/Library` on my Mojave machine is 28 GB. But I fully support the "if something goes wrong it's easier to restore" part, squeezing a few gigabytes out of a backup isn't a good idea.

Comment: @nohillside Most of it will be read-only and so only backed up once, so it represents good 'value' space on the backup disk. 28Gb on a 1+Tb volume is still small.

Comment: Ben, thanks, picking apart your list ....... would you say it is *only stuff which is **"installed with or by Applications"*** ... ?  Example, I install XYZ software; it (say) downloads or builds and installs some very large accessories, and it does that in /Library -> if the Mac blows up, the only downside is I would have to (essentially) re-install XYZ (and indeed allow it to yet again download it's vast helper files).  Is that correct?  Or do I misread you?  cheers !

Comment: @Fattie If your Mac blows up, or you do a clean install of the OS, then you'll need to reinstall all your apps. Apps that have an installer package may well put stuff in /Library. Some apps will move stuff there if you click OK, like BBEdit Helper tools. Some apps, like Garageband, will download extra stuff there. However, there may be situations when one file of folder amongst many gets accidentally deleted or modified, and it's easier to restore than reinstall the whole thing.

Comment: @benwiggy  Right.  I wanted to clarify that /Library seems to *not* contain any "user files", let us say, "stuff you made with apps".  That does *seem* to be the case.  Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Summarizing the info discovered,

#### /Library ***does NOT*** contain any "user information", let us say, anything "***you*** made or created" with apps.

It seems it only contains stuff "the apps keep in there".

Thus, it can safely be ignored.

If you do ignore it, the only downside may be having to reinstall some apps, or, the apps will need to reinstall some extensions, etc (and these days it's trivial and takes no time to reinstall apps).

Comment: I have a hard time bringing "it can safely be ignored" and "having to reinstall some apps" together. Also, things like the default Webserver directory is in `/Library`, as are a lot of systemwide installations like Fonts, Perl libraries etc. I doubt it's so easy to reinstall everything (assuming you even remember *what* exactly to install). It may work for your use case, but I wouldn't recommend this as a general solution.

Answer (score -3):

Unhide your Library folder, and then you will be able to see it in the Time Machine settings.

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library/
```

Comment: OP is asking about the pros/cons of excluding /Library, not how to exclude ~/Library. Your method is unnecessary anyway, as making ~/Library visible is supported as a Finder View Options checkbox when in ~/

Comment: My bad! Google redirected me here, and I didn't read the question.Time machine did not show me the folder. That's why I needed this method.